# Get height of document content including absolute/fixed positioned elements

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I need to resize an iframe to match its **content**, but the height properties I have tried don't account for elements with `position: fixed`.

Assume a document with only two elements with the `absolute` and `fixed` classes.

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
}
```

- `html.scrollHeight` 0 (viewport height in Opera/Firefox)
- `html.offsetHeight` 0
- `body.scrollHeight` 0 (viewport height in Chrome)
- `body.offsetHeight` 0
- `body.outerHeight` 0

If I add `html { position: relative; }`, `html.scrollHeight` will be 100px in Chrome, but no value will be 200px. At first I also had an issue with floats, but I solved that by adding a clearfix to `body`.

I made a jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/ehixiq

If it's not possible to get the real height, what would be my best workaround? I only need to support the latest versions of Opera, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The answer here solves this problem very elegantly: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928101/finding-the-full-height-of-the-content-of-a-page-document-that-can-have-absolute

Answer (score 2):

I've found the best way is to use javascript as it can get the height reliably after rendering. In a recent project I did this with jQuery to get full height of the window:

```
$(document).height()
```

You could do something like this for element heights:

```
$('.element2').height($('.element1').height())
```

Update:

```
$('iframe').height($('iframe').parent().height())
```

Comment: jQuery's `height()` reports the entire viewport height, not the content

Comment: Only $(document) is the viewport height, passing an element will be element height (+padding). If by content you mean text within an element, perhaps put a span around the text and then do $('.element span').height(). Also updating answer to include more specific example of parent/child height calculation.

Comment: Maybe I'm unclear, but I need to get the height of the content in the iframe's document, so if the highest element inside the iframe is 200px high, I want to resize the iframe to 200px. This is not a problem for elements with `position: static` as I can get the content height with offsetHeight or scrollHeight from the iframe document, but it doesn't work with fixed/absolute elements inside the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could figure out was to get the actual bottom position of all elements:

```
var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'));
var elHeights = [];
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  elHeights.push(els[i].scrollTop + els[i].offsetHeight);
}
var docHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, elHeights);
```

Browsers managed between 5-100k operations per second on a DOM with 100 elements, and in my case that's about the size most documents will have.