# Get height at which scroll bars will appear in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's a couple of ways to ask this question:

- How can I get the height (in pixels) at which the page will start having scroll bars? In other words, how do i get the window height at which a scroll bar will appear?
- How can I get the maximum height of all elements on the page that don't have relative 
  heights (e.g. height: 100%)?

This question is related, but the answer doesn't do what I want in the case of relative heights: [Finding the full height of the content of a page/document that can have absolutely positioned elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928101/finding-the-full-height-of-the-content-of-a-page-document-that-can-have-absolute)

I made a js fiddle of what I'm talking about: http://tinyurl.com/kgf8dae . Unfortunately, jsfiddle seems to break the relative height put on div e - run it as an html page in a normal browser to see the real behavior.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Perhaps there's a different way to go about it. Also, you'll want to consider the situation when there are horizontal scrollbars which may affect when vertical scroll bars appear.

Comment: I want to alert an upper iframe what height they should set their iframe to. I want it to be generic so that the method for determining height isn't page specific, and I want it to give me the minimum height the page should be.

Comment: edit: "... minimum height the page [*can*] be [without cutting off the page or causing scroll bars"

Comment: I suppose one way to do this would be to find all elements on that page with relative heights, display:none them, then check the height, and redisplay them afterward

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstand the question. In general, if the window height is less than the document height you will get a vertical scrollbar.

So in jQuery the check might look like this:

```
if( $(document).height() > $(window).height() ){ /* There will be a scrollbar */ }
```

You can perform this check within DOM changing and window resizing events to ascertain if a scrollbar has appeared. To preemptively determine if an event would cause a scrollbar to appear can be tricky and would likely require some understanding of the page and potential events to handle efficiently.

Comment: I'm not looking for whether scroll bars *have* appeared, I'm looking for when scroll bars *would* appear.

Comment: @BT This is in the answer: Scrollbars *would* appear when `$('body').outerHeight(true) == $(window).height()`.

Comment: Yes, and how do I get when that is the case? For a page with elements that have relative heights (e.g. height: 100%), $('body').outerHeight() changes as the window height changes. So to know what the height would be, the window would have to already be in that position. This question is more complicated than you guys think.

Comment: Do you have a demo you can share to better illustrate what you're after? Perhaps use jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Maybe I'll put that together this weekend, but i'm pretty busy til sunday.

Comment: Here's a js fiddle of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/RMe3n/1/ . Unfortunately, jsfiddle seems to break the relative height put on div e - run it as an html page in a normal browser

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged through jQuery so I'm going to use jQuery; even though it's not mentioned in the question body.

a) It sounds like you want to get the height of the viewport (window); which can be retrieved like this:

```
var height = $(window).height();
```

If the height of the document (page) exceeds the height of the window, and there are no CSS properties blocking the display of scrollbars, then scrollbars will indeed by visible.

```
if( $(document).height() > $(window).height() )
```

b) This is going to be a bit trickier, in the sense the only way off the top of my head is to query every DOM element.. **this is not a elegant solution**; and *in fact I'd ask you to reconsider your approach if you really you must do this*. That said.. for curiosity...

If you're looking for the max height, in the sense of the largest element - then this would work:

```
// Get height of largest element.
var max_height = 0;

$('*').each( function(){
    // skip <html> and <body>
    if( ( $(this).get(0) == $('body').get(0) ) || ( $(this).get(0) == $('html').get(0) ) )
      return;

    var current_height = $(this).height();

    if( current_height > max_height )
      max_height = current_height;
});
```

For example, running that on this page...

```
> console.log( max_height );
570
```

However, I'm not sure if you want the maximum height of all combined elements.. In which case we obviously need to add all the elements up, but there's the obvious problem: elements are nested!

If this is what you want, then by using `.children()` we can just iterate through the lengths of the elements that are immediate children of your containing element/body.

```
// Get height of all combined elements
var combined_height = 0;

$('body').each( function(){  // replace with containing element?
    combined_height = combined_height + jQuery(this).height();
});
```

For example, running that on this page:

```
> console.log(combined_height);
2176
```

Comment: So actually, the answer to both questions should be the same. $(window).height() does not give me at what page height scroll bars will appear - it instead gives the height of the viewing window.

Comment: In the context of displaying a web page, should the height of the page be larger than than the height of the viewport scrollbars will appear unless otherwise set by hiding the overflow using CSS. So in regards to question 1; I stick by the answer.

Comment: You're certainly correct, but i'm looking for that "height of the page" rather than "height of the viewport". $(window).height() is the "height of the viewport".

Comment: Also, I fail to see how both questions can have the same answer when one essentially, one is "How can I determine at which height scrollbars will appear?" - and the second one can be interpreted in multiple ways. Instead I'm guessing you've downvoted both answers as you haven't asked the question very clearly to begin with.. Regardless, ```$(document).height()``` will provide you the height of the document/page.

Comment: Read the SO question i linked up there - then maybe you'll understand. It is not as simple as getting $(document).height()

Comment: May I suggest an edit to the question then, more to clarify whether I am understanding it correctly now. *"Given a page where elements are absolutely positioned so as to extend beyond the bounds of the document; how can I position of the lowest element? Furthermore, how can I calculate the height of the page to take this in to account?"* - **If that's actually your question then the original question here bares hardly any resemblance to it! Hence the confusion!**

Comment: Hey Fergus, thanks for trying to understand, but the question you proposed is the *other* question I asked (which is linked in this question). I already have an answer to that question. This question is about taking into account elements that have relative heights (e.g. "height: 100%"), as is described in my question. Sorry if its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML/CSS from the example your provided via (jsfiddle.net/RMe3n/1). The answer is and always will be 242.

However, I assume you're looking for a more dynamic approach. Running the following after DOM ready will also produce 242:

```
var answer = 0;
$('#absolutes > div').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    if(answer < h) answer = h;
})
alert(answer);
```

While the above will solve for the particular HTML/CSS you provided it makes a lot of assumptions about the page's HTML structure and CSS.

Is it possible that the problem you are attempting to address with JS could be resolved in a "cleaner" way by adjusting the HTML/CSS of your page?

---

If you are looking for a fool proof JS method to account for ALL the multitude of unique layouts/styles that exist now and may exist as more CSS3 display types are adopted in the future I believe you're out of luck. There is no recommendable, consistent, efficient way to do so.

*Note: If this is more than just a theoretical discussion, consider being more specific about the exact scenario you are faced with as there is likely a vastly different approach that may resolve the issue.*

Comment: I'm looking for a general javascript function I can call to evaluate a page automatically. Adjusting the HTML/CSS is exactly what I want to avoid.